# Keycloak 403 error with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, web, controller, keycloak

I try to integrate keycloak on my web app, which is using spring boot but i have an issue that I don't know exactly how to deal with.

I have here the application.properties

```
keycloak.auth-server-url=http://localhost:8080/auth
keycloak.realm=SpringBoot
keycloak.resource=GCE
keycloak.public-client=true
keycloak.ssl-required=external

keycloak.security-constraints[0].authRoles[0]=user
keycloak.security-constraints[0].securityCollections[0].patterns[0]=/start

server.port=8180
spring.session.store-type=none
```

Here is my controller, and where I start the app

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class GCEApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {

SpringApplication.run(GCEFinalApplication.class, args);
}
}

@Controller
class AppController {

@GetMapping(path = "/start")
public String start(){
    System.out.println(1);
    return "start";
}

@GetMapping(path = "/logout")
public String logout(HttpServletRequest request) {
    try {
        request.logout();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
    }
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    if (session != null) {
        session.invalidate();
    }
    return "/";
}
}
```

This is my index page, and it is in resources/static

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" 
xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3"
xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="/start">Start</a>
</body>
</html>
```

And the start page is .ftl template

```
<#import "/spring.ftl" as spring>
<html>
<h1>My products</h1>

<br>
<a href="/logout">Logout</a>
</html>
```

When I try to access the start page it gave me 403 error. 
It works to connect to Keycloak, and the session starts but I think the redirect is not ok

Comment: Setting and code looks like correct. Can you share how you configured the client in the Keycloak Console ? Are there any errors in the Keycloak server log ? Which versions are you using ?

Comment: The user that tried to connect didn't have the right role and it was impossible for him to access the content